# Removing Values from a HashSet that are connected to a key?

Tags: java, collections, maps, hashset

I want to withdraw a student from a school class. The following method is not removing the value? Ideas please:

```
public static void withdrawStudent(String student) {
    enrollments.values().remove(student);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        enroll("101", "Pat");
        withdrawStudent("Pat");
}
```

// Here is part of the class.

```
private static HashMap<String, Set<String>> enrollments = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

public static void enroll(String unit, String student) { 
    Set<String> studentsSet = enrollments.get(unit); 
    if(studentsSet == null) { 
        studentsSet = new HashSet<>(); 
    } 
    studentsSet.add(student);
    enrollments.put(unit, studentsSet); 
}
```

Comment: Try `enrollments.remove("101");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried that, wasn't working. printing out the value still

Comment: re-reading your question, I believe what you want is to remove `Pat` from the `101` Set - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to remove a String, while `enrollments.values()` returns a Set of String. A possible fix would be this, but keep in mind that this would remove the student from every enrollment.

```
public static void withdrawStudent(String student) {
    for (Set<String> studentSet : enrollments.values()) {
        studentSet.remove(student);

    }
}
```